# EC2 cannot access S3 in the same account with proper IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

I have two EC2 instances: `ec2-1` and `ec2-2`, one s3 bucket: `bucket-1`, all in the same aws account.

both instances are associated with the same IAM role which has this trust relationship:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

for permissions policy, this IAM role has `AmazonS3FullAccess`

I have set up aws credentials via `aws configure`, typed in the same access/secret keys on both instances.

These two instances have the same VPC, security group, but somehow, `ec2-1` could access `bucket-1` via aws cli, while `ec2-2` cannot and threw this error:

```
aws s3 ls

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

Could anyone help advise here?

Thanks!

Comment: You nailed it, thanks John! Feel free to post this as an answer and I'll accept it with more details of how I was able to resolve this based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, permissions are granted to an Amazon EC2 instance by assigning an **IAM Role** to the instance. Any software on the instance that uses an AWS SDK will automatically retrieve credentials associated with the IAM Role.

However, you then mention that you used `aws configure` to store credentials on the instance. This will likely **override the permissions** granted via the IAM Role.

You can use `aws sts get-caller-identity` to display which IAM entity is currently being used to call AWS. This will help you debug which entity is being used so you can then check if that entity has sufficient permissions.

If I had to guess, one instance is probably using the IAM Role permissions (and is working) while the other is using the locally-stored credentials (and is failing).

Comment: Yes, thanks John, just as you predicted: calling `aws sts get-caller-identity` revealed that on my two EC2 instances, I was using two different IAM roles to access aws cli, it was the IAM role that's working, so I simply removed `rm -rf ~/.aws/` on my 2nd EC2 and let it use the IAM role and it started working, many thanks!